# I need one element in xs:all to repeat twice

Tags: xsd

```
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="AN" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ME" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="preview" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="NZ" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="RE" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="RU" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="AU" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="SE" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="CM" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In the above code, i want the element "ME" to be used twice in XML and other elements should be used exactly once but in anyorder.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is the following. However while this is fine under XSD 1.1, its not under XSD 1.0.

```
<xs:element name="MyElm">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="AN" />
            <xs:element name="ME" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" />
            <xs:element name="preview" />
            <xs:element name="NZ" />
            <xs:element name="RE" />
            <xs:element name="RU" />
            <xs:element name="AU" />
            <xs:element name="SE" />
            <xs:element name="CM" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In XSD 1.0, I'm pretty sure this is not possible. If you can live without them being 'in any order' then you can use a xs:sequence, and if you can live with 0-1 and 0-2 items then you could use a xs:choice. But that's as close as you can get.